# How can make white line effect on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I make this **[effect](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/cp55xWGaXanY08ieb4aGKBAVY9yMqxBElf1D3ft7NtCxj72LDphOl5cyYoAQPIhSAl8Vwg=w1332-h487)** 
to use this [image](http://www.indonesia.travel/public/media/images/upload/poi/Danau%20Segara%20Anak%20-%20Gallery.jpg)

I have to use this effect on many images so I can't use white effect image.

And it is possible or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try after or before **Pseudo Elements** to make this.

[**[Demo]**](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_j/xqLf0spa/1/)

```
.pillar:after, .pillar:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 350px;
  width: 64px;
  top: 16px;
  left: 70px;
  background-image: url(http://www.indonesia.travel/public/media/images/upload/poi/Danau%20Segara%20Anak%20-%20Gallery.jpg);
}
```

Comment: @manwal Ooops you are right.

Comment: @Manwal This should work for dynamicaly added image...

Comment: @Maddy no maddy you are give perfect answer , my way of asking is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is possible
here you can download the plugin: http://almogbaku.github.io/imageMask/

1. Create image element

   `<img src="image.jpg" class="mySelector" />`
2. Create mask image(black will keep stay, and the transparent will cutted of) 
   mask
3. Add imageMask query to the ready event. use function .imageMask(path_to_mask)

   `$( document ).ready( function() {
       $( ".mySelector" ).imageMask( "mask.png" );
   } );`
4. You can add some callback handler

   `$( document ).ready( function() {
       $( ".mySelector" ).imageMask( "mask.png", function( $canvas ) {
           console.log( 'Do something here!', $canvas );
       } );
   } );`
5. DONE!

Comment: Exactly same as my answer, except you have to load a plugin to manage with black background =)

Answer (score -1):

It is basically possible in many ways.

The easiest, I think, is to create a "mask" with all the white lines, and using a transparent background.
Then simply put your mask on top of your image, and voila.

**EDIT**

Here's your mask : [Click !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGN28.jpg)

**EDIT 2**

If you want to protect your image against copy, maybe it's better to not upload it, and just showing modified img online =)

Comment: I think he wants to 'protect' his images. So, doing that, won't help him that much.

Comment: @TraianTatic What do you mean by "protecting" image?

Comment: @VeeeneX I think he's thinking about an anti-copy system

Comment: @VeeeneX Making it unusable. It can be copied ofc, it's loaded in the browser but, if it's full of white lines, it can't be used while it's still visible enough to offer a good preview.

Comment: Edited my answer about that =)